# How to prevent characters to overlap

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm really struggling at something that I had imagined to be pretty simple: I have two meshes (fighters) instantiated from the same prefab and I want them to not overlap. The prefab is set to have a box collider. Ideally, I let the animator handles the position. I've tried several approaches:

1. Configure the animators to "Animate Physics". No collision is detected
2. Uncheck root motion and move characters using game object's transform's position. No collision is detected
3. Uncheck root motion, add a rigid body to each character and move character using game object's position. Collision is detected, but the reaction is governed by physics which makes it look unnatural since all I want is to just avoid the characters to pass through each other i.e. just want characters to be pushed back until they don't collide anymore

I really would like to avoid going with a manual approach to this. How would I prevent this overlapping?

Edit: isTrigger is unset on box colliders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rigidbody is highly configurable and you want a limited set of the physics functionality it can offer. Go with the third solution you enumerated and freeze the rotation in the rigidbody. See [the rigidbody page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) for more details.

As a side note, you might consider using a capsule collider, so that characters "slide" around each other more easily.

Comment: Thanks! I think this got me closer to what I'm aiming for. So I restricted rotation and it now it feels more natural. However, it still feels as physics engine is getting on my way. I'm getting some unexpected "jumps" while pushing the other character. I restricted the Y position, but I imagine that to be troublesome when implementing jump. Also, it seems I can't find a way to avoid pushing the other character continuously which is also something I don't want.

Comment: One other thing that'll cause issues is if you control the transform's position manually. Instead of doing transform.position= you should set the rigidbody's velocity value to make them move (rigidbody.velocity=).

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not necessarily preventing overlap, you could create a perimeter for characters. It would be rather simple depending on what you're doing.

If you want to set up a distance perimeter to prevent characters from getting too close to one another you could use the following equation

```
Vector3 focalPOne = focalPointOfCharacterOne();
Vector3 focalPTwo = focalPointOfCharacterTwo();

float dx = focalPOne.x - focalPTwo.x;
float dy = focalPOne.y - focalPTwo.y;
float dz = focalPOne.z - focalPTwo.z;

// calc distance along z plane
if (Math.Sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) < minDistance)
{
    // person is too close to the others head.
    if (Math.abs(dz) < minHeightAbove)
    {
        // go to previous position.
    }

    // if there is no vertical elivation, you can go
    // straight to moving them back to previous position
}
enter code here
```

If this wasn't what you're looking for, please let me know so I can edit or remove it.

The perimeter created would look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to have your characters with their respective box colliders register a collision, both need to have a RigidBody component. That's the only way to make sure the characters do not go through each other considering they share a prefab.

You don't have to handle the separation/rejection of the characters via the physics engine though. Simply make the box collider trigger, and then handle the separation via code in a C# script using onTiggerEnter.

There's a collision detection matrix that could help you, found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html. Also this image summarizes it beautifully (in the documentation it's in two separate tables for some reason):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is really useful information.

Comment: @mdonati thanks! Any chance I can get an upvote or a right answer please?

Comment: I need to give it a try considering the fact that I would like to avoid going manual. Giving the options I see so far, I'm afraid it's the only way to go to achieve the gameplay I want. How would you handle separation via code? is there any reference you can point me at? Also would it make any difference if these two wouldn't share a prefab?

Comment: @mdonati, it's relatively simple. You could use trial and error to get the exact behavior you want, but the basic is: use the box collider with isTrigger checked, then add to the gameObject a script with OnTriggerEnter function: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html
You get the other collider in the input. the other collider could be the other character's box collider (it's worthwhile to add a label on the Prefab, or use a layer collision). Once you detected that the other collider is the other character, you can either move your own position or the other.

Comment: OnTriggerEnter does not seem to give me enough information in order to be able to calculate how much do I need to push objects away so they don't collide anymore. It seems the method I should be using is OnCollisionEnter since that's the one that gives contact information, but then OnCollisionEnter is not being called for triggers.

Comment: I use Code such as: private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Transform otherTransform = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
And as a result I have the other character's full Transform information. I can then look at the distance between the local character's position and the other Transform position, and just change them as needed. Without any code to play with, it's difficult to give you more specific help. Any chance I can get an upvote for good behavior, if this was helpful so far?

Comment: Really appreciate you hanged in there with me. I ended up using rigid bodies with constraints since I really don't want to mess with collision resolution because I may need to add more complex gameplay in the future like a character jumping over another and stuff like that.

Comment: If you want to handle the movement manually, probably a better solution is to have non-trigger colliders, no rigid bodies, and use this method to detect collisions: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html